# Getting a small blue line between thumbnails with fancybox link

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm putting together a small website and using fancybox for image galleries. For some reason, there is a very small blue line (not a border) separating each thumbnail on all pages... it wasn't like this when I initially set it up, so i'm not sure what is causing the problem now.

Have a look here for example: http://inkylizard.com/ceramics.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple CSS issue. Add a rule to your anchors to fix it like

```
.fancybox {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```